# 2 Masses on a table confusion - Normal force and weight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, gravity, mass

[image]

Forces up are greater than forces down. However, the masses on the table obviously don't start flying upwards. Am I missing a force here?

Comment: There are too many forces in this picture. If you want to draw it like this, yes, you are missing the N3L pair of $N_2$, which is why it is not balanced. Ideally, you should be drawing just for the $m_1$ mass alone, so that you can see precisely how the things are balanced.

Comment: What does the L stand for in N3L?

Comment: @photon If you sum all forces with direction , then all forces cancels out. $(M_1+M_2)g$ is canceled by $N_1$ and $M_2g$ is canceled by $N_2$. Try to balance forces on each mass seperately.

Comment: Newton's Third Law

Comment: N2 is an internal force of the two block system and should not be added to the external forces, (m1+m2)g down and N1 up which sum to zero for equilibrium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $N_{12}$ means the normal force on body $1$ due to body $2$ and the forces are colour coded to identify the Newton's third law pairs here are the free body diagrams for the three systems under consideration.

[image]

You can then add the forces together for each of the systems and equate each of them to zero as there is static equilibrium.